# Github Workflow that forces developers to check box on PR before merge (passing status checks based on issue_comment events)

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to create a workflow that makes a comment with a checklist on a newly opened PR reminding developers to go and update documentation and fail status checks until the developer acknowledges the checklist. Here is my workflow:

```
name: 'PR Tasks Completed Check'
on: 
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, edited, synchronize]
  issues:
    types: [opened, edited, deleted]
  issue_comment:
    types: [created, edited, deleted]
jobs:
  review-checklist:
    name: Make documentation comment on PR
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: "Make comment (if necessary)"
        uses: actions/github-script@v4
        with:
          script: |
            github.issues.createComment({
              issue_number: context.issue.number,
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              body: `### Review Checklist
            - [ ] Documentation updated`,
            })
  require_checklist_c:
    name: "Require Checklist"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [review-checklist]
    steps:
      - uses: mheap/require-checklist-action@v1
        with:
          requireChecklist: false 
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

The problem I'm having is that even though require-checklist-action runs fine and fails the status check appropriately after the PR is opened and the documentation comment is made, when it runs as the result of issue_comment being run after the person checks the box, I can see the workflow running again on the Actions tab but the status check on the PR itself remains in the failed state. Am I not able to pass status checks based on `issue_comment` events?  Or is there some other problem i'm fundamentally misunderstanding?

Comment: The triggers `issues` and `issue_comment` run on your default branch. Unlike `pull_request`, which runs in the context of your pull request. Perhaps you could try and use the checks API manually. Although I think a GitHub app would be better suited for this use-case.

Answer (score 1):

It's a tricky one! Your workflow gets activated by the issue_comment event, but the PR status check persists in its failed state. The disconnect likely lies in how the issue_comment event isn't prompting the require-checklist-action to reassess the checklist's status.

Here's a way to think about it: PR status checks and issue_comment events aren't inherently tied together. While your workflow is indeed being triggered, the status check might not be updating because its state doesn't depend directly on the event that got fired off. They operate in separate spheres, essentially; events launch workflows, while status checks pertain to the PR's "state".

To navigate this, you might need to investigate how to explicitly update the status check in response to an issue_comment event. Alternatively, consider using a different event that impacts the PR's status check directly.

Now, that's one approach, and I don't have full context on your use case but I know GitHub Actions can be quite intricate and testing can get tedious. Fortunately, there are some checklist builders in the GitHub marketplace exactly for this kind of process. One of them, [Pull Checklist](https://www.pullchecklist.com/), I've actually developed myself (fair warning, slight bias here!). This tool and others like Pull Request Checklist Buddy can help you put together blocking checklists with conditions, greatly simplifying your PR workflow management. They might be worth a look if you want to sidestep the hassle of GitHub Actions.

I hope this gives you a clearer path forward. Debugging workflows can be complex, but with a bit of perseverance, you'll crack it! Hope this helped.

Comment: I would go with Pull Request/Issue Template for checkbox creation.
https://docs.github.com/en/communities/using-templates-to-encourage-useful-issues-and-pull-requests/creating-a-pull-request-template-for-your-repository
And then add only workflow for checking if it's checked.